# Basic JQuery Get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript for a school project, and decided to use JQuery for getting information from a site. I've never used it before so I don't know what I'm doing, and most tutorials seem to confuse me. What I have so far to get the information is:

```
$(function getRoutes(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/50017'
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        }
    })

});
```

This returns "Unexpected identifier" at line 6. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a `,` at the end of `url: ...`

Try this:

```
$(function getRoutes() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/50017',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems to get rid of the error, but doesn't paste anything into the console

Comment: Brings up this error: 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/50017. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.'

Comment: Had to download something for chrome. Now it's working. Thanks for saving my grade buddy

Answer (score 1):

Unwanted symbols in your code, and as mentioned b @Johan you have missed a `,` after `url`, 3 Possible variations you want:

**If you want to call it using `getRoutes()` then**

```
function getRoutes(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/50017',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        }
    })

};

// Invoking Manually (sort of).
getRoutes();
```

**Or if you want it to be **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**

```
// Will be invoked immediately.
(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/50017',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        }
    })

})();
```

**Or on DOM Ready you may need that `$`**

```
$(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/50017',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: I don't see a downvote, but you failed to address the issue that caused the error message mentioned in the question.

Comment: Your third alternative will do the same as what he currently got.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson i dont think so, in his case he may need to call the function.

Comment: He's right, it's exactly the same as your version except that the function parameter is named.

Answer (score 0):

Probably slightly better:

```
function getRoutes(locationid) {
  var routesURL = 'http://orbis.stanford.edu/api/sites/' + locationid;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: routesURL
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.dir(data);
  });
}
getRoutes(50017);
```

This uses the jQuery promise returned by the ajax